# Email configuration on Different Cpanel and website on Aws

Tags: email, dns, cpanel, web-hosting

I have a scenario that gives me headache for a while now. I bought a domain on Namecheap, hosting on Godaddy cpanel, but later decided to host on Aws ec2 instance, but I don't want to use the SES service from Amazon. Now that was successful.On trying to setup the email account on the Godaddy cpanel, I can only send emails , but not receive. I tried several mx record settings, but none worked.

Domain from Namecheap  --- works
Email service - Godaddy Cpanel email -- can only send, no receipts.
Website hosting - Aws ec2 ----works

I would like to know the correct setup for this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is that you are trying to host on EC2? Is it an application? 
Where is your Email Hosting done? Is it in GoDaddy?

Comment: I hosted a simple website on EC2 and that is not my problem, the only problem is how to set MX record so I can be able to receive emails in godaddy' cpanel. I already can send emails from the setup webmail, but can't receive emails. That is , to be able to host my email on Godaddy  cpanel. Note that domain name is from namecheap.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you have to change your MX Record entries in your DNS.

You have to add the MX entry provided by the cpanel for that particular domain in your dns to get your incoming emails service working.

You are able to send emails because there is no need of MX when you are sending mails. You are using SMTP for sending mails out from your server.

Your website should be working if you have added your amazon ec2 instance public ip in your DNS.

You can make things simpler by moving your dns to cpanel i.e. on godaddy server by changing nameservers in your name cheap panel which is given by godaddy guys. You then have to add A record which must be pointing to your AWS ec2 instance public IP and your MX must be set bydefault in your cpanel server.